# ESRI ArcGIS collapses geometry arrays for nearby points

Tags: arcgis-server, route

When calling ESRI ArcGIS Solve Route REST API (https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/solve-route.htm), if the input stops are nearby (for example -121.31678799999997, 44.024490000000071 and -121.316788, 44.023907, the returned output considers them as a single point in the features -> geometry JSON element. If there are total n input stops, there should ideally be n-1 arrays in the output (each for a path between two stops) but if a pair of points like the above is in the stops, they 'collapse' and the output contains only n-2 arrays. How to prevent them from 'collapsing'? I have tried using the parameter outputGeometryPrecision with value 0 and then again with value 1 and value esriCentimeters for outputGeometryPrecisionUnits to no avail.

Comment: The points are processed at the precision of the network layer. The only way to make them *more* precise is to create your own routing service. Note that a millionth of a degree is not more than 11cm, and the inputs to most routers are unlikely to be more accurate than 5-10 *meters*, and the road surface itself is tens of meters wide. If you have points within a decimeter of each other, they may well be duplicate.

Comment: The points in question, are 50 plus feet away on google maps - our application, although not requiring precision to the level of centimeters or lower, does require differentiating points which are at this distance.